# Getting undefined in xaxis Histogram Bokeh/Python when applying FuncTickFormatter

Tags: python, bokeh

Getting "Undefined" on Bokeh xaxis(Histogram) using FuncTickFormatter in Python

I have tried formatting the date to a list and running it through FuncTickFormatter in python; I have equally tried placing my date as index and still get same problem. I am new to using bokeh. Thanks a lot for the help.

```
arr_df.head()

    dateL          count  left  right  f_count    f_interval
0   2022-12-29       1    1424  1458     1      1424 to 1458
1   2023-02-02       3    1458  1492     3      1458 to 1492 
2   2023-03-08       3    1492  1527     3      1492 to 1527
```

```py
dicaxis1 = arr_df['dateL'].to_dict()

p = figure(plot_width = 500, plot_height = 500)

select_axis_key = range(0, len(arr_df), 1)
select_axis = {k:v for (k,v) in dicaxis1.items() if k in select_axis_key}

p.xaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=select_axis_key)
p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""var labels = {}; return labels[tick];""" % select_axis)

r = p.quad(bottom=0, top='count', left='datel', right='dater', source=arr_src,
       fill_color='red', line_color='black')

styled_p = style(p)

hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [('Duration', '@f_interval'),
                              ('Numb. of Phases', '@f_count')])
styled_p.add_tools(hover)

show(styled_p)
```

TypeError: Object of type 'range' is not JSON serializable

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proximate cause of this error is that `labels[tick]` does not exist. And there is no particular reason for it to. You have left on Bokeh's default automatic tick choosing, and there is no reason for the tick locations that Bokeh chooses to happen to match whatever keys you have put in `label_dict`. You would need to control the tick locations with a `FixedTicker` to make sure things match up. But things are actually simpler than you are making them, you can set both the ticks you want, and their formats more simply:

```
p.xaxis.ticker = ticks  # specify fixed tick locations
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = label_dict  # as well as their format
```

The keys for `label_dict` should be the same `ticks` you set. It's unclear from the incomplete code you have posted what the actual scale of the x-axis really is. If its datetimes, be aware that the underying units are *milliseconds-since-epoch* so your ticks would need to be expressed that way. Also standard warnings about using floating point numbers as keys in dictionaries apply.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot. Really appreciate your response. So i mapped my ticks as you stated and now am getting: "TypeError: Object of type 'range' is not JSON serializable". Attached is my full code above and edited. Thanks again

Comment: `range` in Python3 returns a generator, but Bokeh will need a concrete realized sequence. You probably want `list(range(0, len(arr_df), 1))`